# Binary Search output error

Tags: java, binary-search

I was doing the binary search for String and it showing output error. I do not know what I missing and I need some advice.

**Here my code :**

```
public static final int Not_Found = -1;

    public static int BS( String[][] record, String x )
{
int low = 0;
int high = record.length - 1;
int mid;

while( low <= high )
{
mid = ( low + high ) / 2;

if( record[ mid ].compareTo( x ) < 0 )
low = mid + 1;
else if( record[ mid ].compareTo( x ) > 0 )
high = mid - 1;
else
return mid;
}

return Not_Found;
    }
```

Its that I missing something? or I have to use other way to find it?

**Here the error :**

error: cannot find symbol
if( record[ mid ].compareTo( x ) < 0 )
                 ^
  symbol:   method compareTo(String)

error: cannot find symbol
else if( record[ mid ].compareTo( x ) > 0 )
                      ^
  symbol:   method compareTo(String)

Comment: You can't compare a string to a string array.

Comment: you are using "String[][] record". use "String[] record" if it is 1d record.

Comment: how should I can work on 2D-array? any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Well `record` is a 2D-array, so `record[j]` will give an array as opposed to a string. Did you maybe mean to use a 1D-array instead?

Comment: Well since the binary search is being done in a 'linear' fashion, maybe you could have a method that stretches a 2D-array into a 1D-array by concatenating all of the rows. Then you could search this new array with the regular binary search. Or similarly you could have a for-loop that searches every row of the 2D <code>record</code> array.

Comment: I will try to do that if that possible, thank for you advice, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

you are using "String[][]" means 2D record. So, record[j] gives corresponding jth column string array. Which can't be compared to a string. So, use "String[] record" if it is 1d record.

Comment: So if I wish to work on 2D, I need to change difference format code? or I just need change some of them?

Comment: look your code have to search for every record[ mid ][i] to compare to String. In this way you can't compare. Take example, record[0][0] = 7, record[1][0]=5, record[2][0] = 0, record[2][1] = 5. your search for 5 will give wrong result because your mid will give wrong mid. You can, do it like this, rec[0] = record[0][0], rec[0] = record[0][1] ...so on (use another temporary array for storing records). Then perform binary search and returned result position convert as record[][] row-col number. I think it will be simpler.